# My Delete modalForm always delete the first object in the dataModel?(Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I made a modal using bootstrap to delete user entries in a list view so i had to iterate with a for loop in the template so it always deletes the first object, also it never closes.  How I can make the button of each entry unique that it deletes this object only.

here's the modal :

```
  {% for obj in patients %}

     <div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDelete"
  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete patient!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this patient?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <form method="POST" action="{% url 'patients:patient_delete' obj.pk %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes" type="submit" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

and here's my triggering button :

```
<button type ="button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete" >Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give all your modal forms the same id. You should disambiguate, for example by adding the primary key to your id, like:

```
{% for obj in patients %}
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete{{ obj.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDelete"
  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete patient!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this patient?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'patients:patient_delete' obj.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes" type="submit" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and as triggering button:

```
<button type ="button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete{{ obj.pk }}">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
btw do you know how to center the modal on the screen as it's now showed on the absolute up.
and it still doesn't close when I click cancel or the close button.